# Deleting random access file in java

Tags: java, file-io, delete-file, random-access

I've created a random access file as follows:

```
 RandomAccessFile aFile = null;
 aFile = new RandomAccessFile(NetSimView.filename, "rwd");
```

I want to delete the file "afile". can anyone suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that:

```
File f = new File(NetSimView.filename);
f.delete();
```

Edit, regarding your comment:

The parameter `NetSimView.filename` seems to be a `File` and not a `String` that contains the path to the file. So simply do:

```
NetSimView.filename.delete();
```

Comment: Or `(new File(NetSimView.filename)).delete();`.

Comment: @romaintiaz :Thanks for your answer but the above code is giving an error:          cannot find symbol    Symbol:Constructor File(java.io.File)

Comment: I had the same problem ... and the code is giving an error : package NetSimView does not exist